# Validar si un input File esta vacio o no con PHP

Tags: php, html

Cordial Saludo.

Espero se encuentren bien, y me puedan ayudar.

Lo que hago es, tengo un formulario HTML, Que envia datos por POST, A PHP, un campo es un input de tipo file  (input="file">), y lo recibo en PHP, Lo que quiero validar es si la varible, viene con un archivo o no.

```
<form method="POST" action="php/archivo.php" id="frm_contact" name="frm_contact" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <input type="file" class="aweform" name="desprendible">
<input type="submit"  class="myButton" id="btn-enviar" Value="Enviar">
</form>
```

///---------------------Archivo PHP-----------------//

```
$desprendible = $_FILES["desprendible"];

if(empty($desprendible)){

echo "No hay datos";

}else{

echo "Hay datos prro";

}
```

Por favor me puedan ayudar.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cordia Saludo.

Logre solucionar el problema.

Si alguien presenta el mismo incoveniente, le dejo la solucion.

Archivo.php

```
$desprendible = $_FILES["desprendible"];

if ($_FILES['desprendible']['name'] != null) {
echo "Tiene datos La variable";
}else{
echo "No hay datos";
}
```

Comment: recuerda aceptar con la palomita tu propia respuesta si le dió solución a tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Para saber si se envió algo por el `$_FILES`  es el siguiente:

```
if (count($_FILES)>0) {
echo 'Se envió algo';
}else{
echo 'no se envió nada';
}
```

para saber si se envió un archivo en concreto sería así:

```
if(isset($_FILES['imagen'])){
echo 'existe';
}else{
echo 'no existe';
}
```